# jquery css getter: right

Tags: jquery, css, getter

I want to execute two different functions depending on the right position of an element, but the function:

```
    $(function(){
var position = $("#telefonofisso").css('right')
$("#telefonofisso").click(function(){
    if (position < 0) {
        $("#telefonofisso").delay(400).animate({right:10},1000)
    }
    else {
        $("#telefonofisso").delay(400).animate({right:-180},1000)
    }
})
})
```

doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Just check what returns `.css('right')`, it should return computed style including pixel

Comment: How can I "depixel" it?

Comment: What do you mean by depixel?

Comment: I mean get a pure numeric value

Comment: I think you want to get rid of "px" at the end. You can do this way
    parseFloat(position.substr(0, posisition.length - 2));

Comment: You'd have better to not rely on any css property but instead using your own logic to check if it is already clicked or not, e.g: `this.clicked = !this.clicked; if(this.clicked){...}else{...}`. Or use jq data object or better toggle a class

Comment: @A Wolff, you got me interested, have you got any links to jq data object material? I don't even know what that is. Thanks

Comment: @TommyD That's just a way to save any element data, e.g, clicked state https://api.jquery.com/data/